# how to insert an XML element from one document to another

Tags: php, xml

first xml

```
<response status="ok">
<Product>
    <name>blbla</name>
    <productGroupPrimary>test2</productGroupPrimary>
    <productGroupSecondary>test</productGroupSecondary>
    <purchasePrice>18</purchasePrice>
    <retailPrice>29</retailPrice>
    <status>active</status>
    <productCode>0001</productCode>
</Product>
<Product>
...
</Product>
```

other xml

```
<response status="ok">
    <StockQuantityInfo productCode="0001" quantityOnStock="5"></StockQuantityInfo>
    <StockQuantityInfo productCode="dhzh" quantityOnStock="5"></StockQuantityInfo>
    ...
</response>
```

now i would like to use php to make the final XML document look like this

```
<response status="ok">
    <Product>
        <name>blbla</name>
        <productGroupPrimary>test2</productGroupPrimary>
        <productGroupSecondary>test</productGroupSecondary>
        <purchasePrice>18</purchasePrice>
        <retailPrice>29</retailPrice>
        <status>active</status>
        <productCode>0001</productCode>
        <stock>5</stock>
    </Product>
    <Product>
    ...
    </Product>
</response>
```

i have no idea how i could do this i am a beginner
I tried that foreach

```
   foreach ($xml2->Product as $item2) {
    $koda2=$item2->productCode;
    foreach ($xml3->StockQuantityInfo as $item3) {
        $koda3=$item3->productCode;
        if ($koda2 ==$koda3 ) { 
        $zaloga=$item3->quantityOnStock;
        $Product=$xml2->Product->addChild('zaloga',$zaloga);
        } 
    }
```

the result is that it doesn’t do anything to me, there’s no change, I have a mistake somewhere, or I’m thinking in the wrong direction

Comment: _“i have no idea how i could do this i am a beginner”_ - then you should go and try to read up on it. This site is a place to discuss problems with code you _have_ written, not to be asking for extended tutorials. Please go read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I tried that 

    foreach ($xml2->Product as $item2) {
    $koda2=$item2->productCode;
    foreach ($xml3->StockQuantityInfo as $item3) {
     $koda3=$item3->productCode;
     if ($koda2 ==$koda3 ) { 
     $zaloga=$item3->quantityOnStock;
     $Product=$xml2->Product->addChild('zaloga',$zaloga);
     } 
    }

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Post code you have tried inside the question, properly formatted, not in comments where it is hardly readable. And give an actual _problem description_ – you tried something, fine, but what was the actual _result_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using DOM (not SimpleXML) for this. `DOMXpath::evaluate()` allows you to fetch the quantity for a product directly using an expression.

```
// bootstrap the documents
$products = new DOMDocument();
$products->loadXML($productsXML);
$productsXpath = new DOMXpath($products);
$stocks = new DOMDocument();
$stocks->loadXML($stockXML);
$stocksXpath = new DOMXpath($stocks);

// iterate the "Product" elements
foreach ($productsXpath->evaluate('//Product') as $product) {
    // get the product code
    $code = $productsXpath->evaluate('string(productCode)', $product);
    // get the quantity of from the stocks response
    $expression = 'number(//StockQuantityInfo[@productCode="'.$code.'"]/@quantityOnStock)';
    $quantity = $stocksXpath->evaluate($expression);
    // output expression and result for demonstration purposes
    var_dump(
        $expression, $quantity
    );
    // validate quantity is a number
    if (!is_nan($quantity)) {
        // append to "Product"
        $product
          ->appendChild(
              $products->createElement('Stock')
          )
          ->textContent = $quantity;
    }
} 

echo "\n", $products->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
string(65) "number(//StockQuantityInfo[@productCode="0001"]/@quantityOnStock)"
float(5)

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response status="ok">
<Product>
    <name>blbla</name>
    <productGroupPrimary>test2</productGroupPrimary>
    <productGroupSecondary>test</productGroupSecondary>
    <purchasePrice>18</purchasePrice>
    <retailPrice>29</retailPrice>
    <status>active</status>
    <productCode>0001</productCode>
<Stock>5</Stock></Product>
</response>
```